# Python depth of elements in heap using heapq

Tags: python, heap

ive been working on this question for a day now. I have a list of frequencies and i want to put that in a heap. Im using heapq. The problem is finding the depth of each of those frequencies when placed in huffman tree.
Ive tried implementing my own class of binary tree but I cant seem to get it right.
Does anyone know how to find the depth of each elements in a heap using the module heapq in python there must be an easier way? Im using it for encoding. Thank you!

Comment: A heap and a Huffman tree are not the same thing, but you seem to be using one as a substitute for the other. Can you explain a bit more about what exactly you're looking for? Can you show your current code? The depth of an item in a binary heap (like those produced by `heapq`) is simply `floor(log2(index+1))`. I'm not sure there's any easy equivalent for a Huffman tree.

Comment: Im looking for the cost of the huffman tree given a list of frequencies. Ive been told I can use heapq. To find the cost you have to find the depth of the frequency to say it simply. I have a bunch of code theyre all useless. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: ill give you a simple frequency l=[70,37,20,3] depth for each one is 1,2,3,3 to get cost of huffman encoding which is 213. the fixed encoding cost is 260

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea is that you can use a priority queue (implemented with a heap) to build a Huffman tree. Or, if you just need the depths of the items in the tree, you can simply increment an appropriate counter:

```
import heapq

def huffman_depths(frequencies):
    depths = [0] * len(frequencies)

    heap = [(f, [i]) for i, f in enumerate(frequencies)]
    heapq.heapify(heap)

    while len(heap) > 1:
        f1, indexes1 = heapq.heappop(heap)         # pop two least frequent nodes
        f2, indexes2 = heapq.heappop(heap)

        frequency = f1 + f2                        # combine them
        indexes = indexes1 + indexes2

        for i in indexes:
            depths[i] += 1                         # increment depth count of each index

        heapq.heappush(heap, (frequency, indexes)) # push the combined result back on

    return depths
```